What are antonyms of pluralism and populism?
Is elitism an antonym of populism? I can't find it in https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/populist.
What is an antonym of pluralism?
Are populism and pluralism nearly synonymous? Is the former more democratic than the latter?

These are loaded terms, and the meaning is highly contextual.  However they don't mean the same thing at all.

The antonym of pluralism is totalitarianism. Pluralism is the rule by multiple factions or parties, totalitarianism is the rule by a single faction or party, or in its extreme form of authoritarianism, by one person.
However, another antonym of pluralism is populism. Populism is the rule by the most popular leaving no room for minority voices which pluralism embodies. An autocrat can be a populist, embodying the will of the majority, but they can’t be a pluralist.

Populism isn't as simple as rule based on what "most people" or "the majority" want.  A politician supported by only 40% of the people can rise to power.
